# Creating Associations between 2 Tables on 2 different Databases with differing host/server - ER_BAD_DB_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have **2 different databases**, on **2 different servers**, with **2 different schemas**.

Essentially, I want to associate one table in one database to another table in the other database, though I am having some trouble in doing so. I've been able to create associations between 2 tables in 2 different databases, on the same server, having problems when they do not share the same host/server.

I'm not entirely sure this is even possible but I hope there is a way around it?

Below is my architecture, outlining the **2 servers**, **2 databases** and outling the association between `property` & `favourites`

```
    +--------------------+--------------------+
    | Server-1           |           Server-2 |
    +--------------------+--------------------+
    | Database-1         |         Database-2 |
    +--------------------+--------------------+
    | property  <----------------- favourites |
    | user               |         notes      |
    | account            |                    |
    +--------------------+--------------------+
```

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/unetiq/using-multiple-databases-with-nodejs-and-sequelize-59e0abcbbe6f) as a starting place, though it, unfortunately, does not cover my use case.

Here is my config, defining options grabbed from and environment file

### config.js

```
import accessEnv from "../utils/accessEnv";
import logger from "../utils/logger";

const defaultOptions = {
  dialect: "mysql",
  logging: msg => logger.debug(msg)
};

module.exports = {
  /**Declaration of databases for my development environment**/
  "development": {
    "databases": {
      "Database1": {
        "database": accessEnv("DB"),
        "username": accessEnv("DB_USERNAME"),
        "password": accessEnv("DB_PASS"),
        "host": accessEnv("DB_HOST"),
        "port": accessEnv("DB_PORT"),
        ...defaultOptions
      },
      "Database2": {
        "database": accessEnv("DB2"),
        "username": accessEnv("DB2_USERNAME"),
        "password": accessEnv("DB2_PASS"),
        "host": accessEnv("DB2_HOST"),
        "port": accessEnv("DB2_PORT"),
        ...defaultOptions
      },
    },
  }
}
```

in my sequelize generated `index.js` for my models, I have updated it a little, based upon [thie article](https://medium.com/unetiq/using-multiple-databases-with-nodejs-and-sequelize-59e0abcbbe6f) listed above to handle 2 different database connections.

### models/index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { default: logger } = require('../utils/logger');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.js`)[env];
const db = {};
const databases = Object.keys(config.databases);

/** Add Databases**/
for (let i = 0; i < databases.length; ++i) {
  let database = databases[i];
  let dbPath = config.databases[database];
  db[database] = new Sequelize(dbPath.database, dbPath.username, dbPath.password, dbPath);
  // Authenticate db connection
  db[database].authenticate()
    .then(() => logger.log(`${dbPath.database} connection successful!`))
    .catch((err) => logger.log(err.stack));
  // Allow schemas
  db[database].dialect.supports.schemas = true;
}

/**Add the Database Models**/
// Add models from database1 folder
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname + '/database1')
  .filter(file =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname + '/database1', file))(db.Database1, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

// Add models from database2 folder
 fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname + '/database2')
  .filter(file =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname + '/database2', file))(db.Database2, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

module.exports = db;
```

Now for the models themselves.

- `Property` is in one server with the `Database1` config.
- `Favourites` is in another server with the `Database2` config.

A `Favourites` will have one `Property`, associating by a `foreignKey` of `propertyId` in the `Favourites` model to `id` of `Property` model.

### models/database1/Property.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Property = sequelize.define("Property", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    accountNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(9),
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    schema: "property_demo",
    tableName: "property",
  });
  Property.associate = (models) => {
    Property.hasOne(models.Favourites, {
      as: 'favourites',
      foreignKey: 'propertyId'
    });
  };
  return Property;
};
```

### models/database2/Favourites.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Favourites = sequelize.define("Favourites", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(),
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    propertyId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    schema: "shortlists",
    tableName: "favourites"
  });
  Favourites.associate = (models) => {
    Favourites.belongsTo(models.Property, {
      as: 'property',
      foreignKey: 'propertyId'
    });
  };
  return Favourites;
};
```

Now, for where the issue lies. When I try to `include` the `Property` model in a `Favourites` model query like below

```
import catchAsync from "../utils/catchAsync";
import Models, { Favourites } from "../models";

export const getFavourites = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const favourites = await Favourites.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Models.Property,
        as: 'property',
      }
    ]
  });
  
  return res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: favourites
  });

});
```

I get the following error

```
"error": {
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "code": "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR",
    "errno": 1049,
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown database 'property_demo'"
  }
}
```

I get that it's looking for `property_demo` on `Server-2` as the `Favourites` model is based on `Server-2` despite `Property` model is in the `property_demo` schema on `Server-1` but is there a way around this so it filters on the correct server/host here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do such query as a plain SQL query?

Comment: MySql would not be my strong point, so I'm not sure other than using a FEDERATED table

Comment: That's the point! Sequelize can't mix tables from two different servers itself

Comment: Just coming back this, adding `separate: true,` as an option in the include for `Property` works if I change the association `Favourites.hasMany(models.Property` & set `sourceKey: 'propertyId'`